# Bubbles appearing on middle aged painted drywall

Tags: paint

At my in-laws, we recently noticed the basement bedroom ceiling had these bumps next to an exterior wall above a window. It's not wet or damp, and they haven't had any known leaks. The bumps look like dripping wet paint, but it's over twenty years since it's last painting. They are hard and dry. Has anyone seen anything like this?

[image: BB sized bumps appeared in ceiling]

Comment: yes, i've seen something like that ..... when did they first appear?

Comment: We first saw them in December this year.. Just a few days ago. Don't know when they showed up since we don't use the room often.

Comment: it is possible that they were formed because excessive paint was used to paint the ceiling,  and you have not noticed them until recently